# Converting Oracle Query to SQL Server - Error 130

Tags: sql-server, function, subquery

The query I have is this:

```
select u1.LastName, u1.FirstName,
    sum(case when not exists(select 1
                     from CaseHistory ch2
                     where ch1.caseid = ch2.caseid
                     and ch2.ActiveDate = somedate
                     ch2.ID in (0, 2, 41))
then 1
else 0
end) as WorkedRecord
from sometables
```

This query works in Oracle, but we're now changing over to SQL Server.  In SQL Server we get the following error:

> Error 130: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or 
>   a subquery.

Here's my solution:

I ended up doing an in-line view and then summing that. I did something like this:
select sum(a.WorkedRecord)
from 
(select
(case when not exists(select 1 
                     from CaseHistory ch2...
                     then 1 else 0 end) as WorkedRecord)
                     from Sometables) a

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the sub-query... could you do a `left join` in this situation, and then total the results of the join?

```
SELECT
    u1.LastName,
    u1.FirstName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ch2.caseid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WorkedRecord
FROM
    sometables s 
    LEFT JOIN CaseHistory ch2 ON
        ch2.caseid = ch1.caseid
        AND ch2.ActiveDate = somedate
        AND ch2.ID in (0, 2, 41)
GROUP BY
    ul.LastName,
    ul.FirstName
```

Comment: I ended up doing an in-line view and then summing that. I did something like this:select sum(a.WorkedRecord)from (select case when not exists(select 1 from CaseHistory ch2...then 1 else 0 end) as WorkedRecord)from Sometables) a                            Sorry, I can't seem to format this code in the edit box so that it's more readable.